# Synchronization for IBM MQ: need or not, if we have only one MQ

Tags: c, ibm-mq

I have 15 years old C program which connects to IBM MQ. It has part of code, which is trying to synchronize something, when has several MQ, which tales from database.

However now we have only one MQ. Do I have to use this method of synchronization?

```
#include "dte_mq.h"    
#include <string.h>    
#include <stdlib.h>    

typedef struct tagDTE_QUEUE_DESCRIPTOR    
{    
    MQHOBJ handle;    
    int    IsSyncpointControled;    
} DTE_QUEUE_DESCRIPTOR, *PDTE_QUEUE_DESCRIPTOR;    

static MQHCONN sHConn = 0;    
static MQLONG  sCompCode = MQCC_OK;    
static MQLONG  sReason = MQRC_NONE;    
static int     sNumOpenQueues = 0;    
static PDTE_QUEUE_DESCRIPTOR sQueues = NULL;    

#define MAX_NUM_OPEN_QUEUES     10    

for(i = 0; i < MAX_NUM_OPEN_QUEUES; i++)    
{    
    if(sQueues[i].handle == -1)    
    {    
         *qd = i;
         sQueues[i].handle = hObj;    
         sQueues[i].IsSyncpointControled = 0;    
         break;    
    }    
}
```

Do we need now this logic, if the value of `q=-1` and in the loop it gets `0` and out of the loop?

If you need it, I can write the whole code into the question.

Comment: If `MAX_NUM_OPEN_QUEUES` is now 1, you don't need the loop.

Comment: what about qd - queue descriptor?

Comment: The code shown doesn't show how `qd` is defined or used; it is impossible to say.

Comment: Are you asking whether you still need to use IsSyncpointControled when you only have one MQ talking to a DB?

Answer (score 0):

> I have 15 years old C program which connects to IBM MQ. It has part of
>   code, which is trying to synchronize something, when has several MQ,
>   which tales from database.

Why don't you read the documentation for the program and the comments in the code to determine what it is doing and/or not doing and whether or not the code needs to be modified.

Secondly, if it has been working for 15 years then why are you messing with something you don't understand?

Third, why don't you hire a qualified MQ contractor to review the code and documentation and do whatever is required to the program?  Because you have posted 7 questions on StackOverflow all related to the same program.